# Adobe Air shared database file

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, air, adobe

Is it possible to install a SQLite database that is readable and writable by all users on a computer (windows or mac)?

As far as I've seen in the API docs the only folders I can read/write access to are local to the specific user of the computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to read/write wherever you want using the [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) class. You just need to resolve wherever you want to point the SQLite to:

```
var db:File = File.resolvePath("/some/path/yourDB.db");
var sqlConnection:SQLConnection = new SQLConnection();
sqlConnection.openAsync(db);
```

However, you have to take into consideration that not all computer use the same absolute paths.  It might be good for you to have the user point to which db they want to open.

Comment: I've done that but the applicationStorageDirectory is local to only 1 user on that computer, not all computer users.

Comment: oh, sorry, I meant to remove that part.  You can use whatever path you want.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. But it does have the cross platform issues you mentioned.

Comment: That it does, but you're doing a 'shared' SQLite db, hence it's impossible to really know where it's going to be on each different system unless you have the user select it using [browseForOpen](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#browseForOpen()).